# Can't ssh or ping Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I've installed Ubuntu server 20.04.02 on a Dell T3500 workstation.
I also selected ssh server installation.
It has an ip address 192.168.1.200 and can ping my router and google.com.
I can login to ssh locally (@loalhost) on the server.
But I can't ssh from my Windows pc on my local network.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.200 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Nor can I ping the Ubuntu server.

```
ping 192.168.1.200

Pinging 192.168.1.200 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

I've tried disabling the firewall to see if that is the problem

```
sudo ufw disable
```

But it didn't help.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your PC and Server on different subnets? Are they REALLY plugged into the same router?

Comment: Can you post the output of two commands from either `cmd` or `powershell` on your Windows host? `ipconfig /all`
& `route print`

Comment: I sorted it out. The syslog mentioned an error with the hostname. I fixed the hostname and all is working. Thanks.